# Create list from a list of dictionaries based on condition in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I need to create a list from a list of dictionary when the attribute `changed` equals to `true`.

```yaml
- name: Ensure Provided id is exist
  user:
    name: "{{ item }}"     
    state: present       
  loop: "{{ user_name_list }}" 
  register: useroutput

- debug: 
    msg: "{{ useroutput }}" 

- name: set fact for make list for id created user
  set_fact:
    created_list_user: "{{ useroutput | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
  vars:
    jmesquery: "results[*].{user_name: name }" 
  when: results[*].changed|lower == true
```

Excepted output:

```yaml
created_list_user: [
  uxapal1005,
  uxapal1006
]
```

Here is the output of task `debug` task on `useroutput`

```json
{
    "msg": {
        "changed": true, 
        "msg": "All items completed", 
        "results": [
            {     
                "changed": false, 
                "item": "uxapal1004", 
                "name": "uxapal1004"
            }, 
            {
                "changed": true, 
                "item": "uxapal1005", 
                "name": "uxapal1005"
            },
            {
                "changed": true, 
                "item": "uxapal1006", 
                "name": "uxapal1006"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Filtering a list of dictionaries is the purpose of the filter [`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr); reducing a list of dictionaries to a simple list is one of the purposes of the filter [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map).

So, your `set_fact` task should be:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    created_list_user: >- 
      {{ 
        useroutput.results
          | selectattr('changed') 
          | map(attribute='name') 
      }}
```

---

If you really want to go with `json_query`, then, make your condition part of the query:

```
results[?changed].name
```

So, your `set_fact` task should be:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    created_list_user: >-
      {{ useroutput | json_query('results[?changed].name') }}
```

---

Given:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg:  >-
      {{
        useroutput.results
          | selectattr('changed')
          | map(attribute='name')
      }}
  vars:
    useroutput:
      results:
        - changed: false
          name: uxapal1004
        - changed: true
          name: uxapal1005
        - changed: true
          name: uxapal1006
```

or

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      {{ useroutput | json_query('results[?changed].name') }}
  vars:
    useroutput:
      results:
        - changed: false
          name: uxapal1004
        - changed: true
          name: uxapal1005
        - changed: true
          name: uxapal1006
```

Those both yield:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - uxapal1005
  - uxapal1006
```